# How to monitor current upload and download speed of an iOS device

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get the current bandwidth speed used by the system or other apps. Something similar to apps like DataFlow or Traffic Monitor do. I’ve been searching for an answer for a while but haven’t found anything useful.
[image]

Screenshot of DataFlow app widget.

I want to create my own widget for iOS 14. But have no idea how to get that data.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: What did you do in the end？